# Power BI how to use offline map

Tags: microsoft-powerbi, dashboard

Is there any way to display an offline map on power bi?
Have tried the basic and ArcGIS map. None of them support offline map.

Answer (score 1):

ShapeMap can import shape files in TopoJSON format - they are saved inside the PBIX file.  There's no background layer capability.

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-desktop-july-feature-summary/

Beware that visual has been in "Preview" status for over 3 years - I expect it will get killed off when they finally remember it is still there.